# jQuery localstorage for dynamic items

Tags: jquery, local-storage, dynamically-generated

I have a series of jQuery draggable / resizable items that are dynamically generated when the user clicks the item in a menu. I cannot figure out how to get localstorage working to save the coordinates and size of these items.

I can get basic localstorage to work if I have a static item that already exists in the HTML when the page is loaded, but this method does not seem to work for dynamic.

Should I be using localstorage.setitem in the code block of each item I dynamically generate?  This seems excessive but writing it as one function has so far failed.

I have studied and tried many, many existing solutions here but nothing that seems to work on modern jquery code, so any assistance is greatly appreciated... thank you.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="outsidecontainer">
  <div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="ui-widget-header">
        <div>Products</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="rack">Rack</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div id="firewall">Firewall</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>Option 3</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="clear">Reset all</button>
  </div>
  <div id="containment-wrapper">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#containment-wrapper {
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  background-size:80%;
}

#outsidecontainer {
  border: 2px solid gray;  
}

#menucontainer {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.remove_block{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  cursor: default;
}

div.remove_block:after{
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\00d7"; /* This will render the 'X' */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  //DYNAMICALLY generate new copies of items
  var i = 1;
  $("#rack").click(function () {
    var dynamic_div =  $("<div />", {
      id: "product" + i
    })
      .css({
        id: "draggable",
        padding: "0.5em",
        //float: "left",
        margin: "0 10px 10px 0",
        cursor: "move",
        position: "absolute",
        background: "white"
        // border: "1px solid #ccc"
      })
      .addClass("draggable", "ui-widget-content");

    $(dynamic_div)
      .append(
        '<div id="block_container"><div class="remove_block"></div><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/759025/3500-1.svg" alt="Rack"></div>'
      )
      .css({
        width: 100
      });

    $(dynamic_div).append("<div>Rack</div>").css({
      "text-align": "center",
      "font-size": "24px",
      padding: " 0.25em",
      "line-height": "100%"
      //"white-space": "nowrap"
    });

    // APPEND THE NEWLY CREATED DIV TO "containment-wrapper".
    $(dynamic_div)
      .appendTo("#containment-wrapper")
      .draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        stack: ".draggable",
        scroll: false
      })
      .resizable({
        minHeight: 100,
        minWidth: 100,
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 500,
        aspectRatio: false
      });
  i++;
});

  //DYNAMICALLY generate new copies of items
  var i = 1;
  $("#firewall").click(function () {
    var dynamic_div =  $("<div />", {
      id: "product" + i
    })
      .css({
        id: "draggable",
        padding: "0.5em",
        float: "left",
        margin: "0 10px 10px 0",
        cursor: "move",
        position: "absolute",
        background: "white",
        border: "1px solid #ccc"
      })
      .addClass("draggable", "ui-widget-content");

    $(dynamic_div)
      .append(
        '<div id="block_container"><div class="remove_block"></div><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/759025/firewall1.svg" alt="Firewall"></div>'
      )
      .css({
        width: 100
      });

    $(dynamic_div).append("Firewall").css({
      "text-align": "center",
      "font-size": "24px",
      padding: " 0.25em",
      "line-height": "100%"
    });

    // APPEND THE NEWLY CREATED DIV TO "containment-wrapper".
    $(dynamic_div)
      .appendTo("#containment-wrapper")
      .draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        stack: ".draggable",
        scroll: false
      })
      .resizable({
        minHeight: 100,
        minWidth: 100,
        maxHeight: 500,
        maxWidth: 500,
        aspectRatio: false
       });
  i++;
});

 //delete object when x is clicked 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove_block', function(events){
   $(this).parents('div').eq(1).remove();
});  
    
  
//END  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is there are currently three events when you would want to store the state.

1. After you append a new item
2. When you delete an item
3. When you stop dragging an item.

Two of those are based on click events and the draggable api has a `stop` event you can use.

The same function can be used each time. It would loop over all the elements and store each type, position and z-index as well as any other meta data you need to reproduce it.

Several things need to be done first.

1. IDs can not be repeated in a page so you need to change to classes instead.
2. I would add a `data-type` attribute so you are able to use the type to reproduce the elements when pge loads with proper image, text etc

The function would be a failry easy `map()` operation to create array of objects that can be stored

Something like:

```
const dataArr = $('#containment-wrapper').children().map(function(){
   const $el = $(this);    
     const obj ={
        type: $el.data('type')// from data attribute,
        left: $el.css('left'),
        top: $el.css('top'),
        zIndex: $el.css('zIndex')

     }
     return obj;
}).get()

localStorage.setItem('elements', JSON.stringify(dataArr))
```

Comment: Yes - thank you. I do not know how to begin with that function.

Comment: OK. Am adding a bit more with regard to that

Comment: All your new items have same id. That's not allowed

Comment: You probably don't need ids.

Comment: Menu ids are ok. They aren't being repeated

Comment: I was able to get the unique ID part functioning. Not sure if it is needed in the long term, but if it gets me a shorter way to localStorage it works.